# Como fazer um botao gravar dados de um formulario com eventos de click

Tags: android

Eu tenho um formulário e desejo salva-lo quando for pressionado o botão *salvar*, a solução que eu fiz não esta funcionando.

```
public class SalvarFormulario extends AppCompatActivity {


EditText Nome;
EditText edtTelefone;
EditText edtObservacao;
EditText edtEmail;
Button btSalvar;


FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_formulario);


    Nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Nome);
    edtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
    edtObservacao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtObservacao);
    edtTelefone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTelefone);
    btSalvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSalvar);






    InicializaFirebase();
    SalvarDados(); // <--- salva os dados 
}




private void InicializaFirebase() {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(SalvarFormulario.this);
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
}

private void limparCampos() {
    Nome.setText("");
    edtTelefone.setText("");
    edtObservacao.setText("");
    edtEmail.setText("");

}
```

Comment: Você deve criar o método `SalvarDados()` se não foi criado ainda, não da pra saber pois o código não está completo.

Comment: ja criei:


public void SalvarDados() {
        // if (btSalvar.isSelected()) {

        Cadastro c = new Cadastro();
        c.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        c.setNome(Nome.getText().toString());
        c.setTelefone(edtTelefone.getText().toString());
        c.setEmail(edtEmail.getText().toString());
        c.setObservacao(edtObservacao.getText().toString());
        databaseReference.child("Cadastro").child(c.getUid()).setValue(c);


        limparCampos();
        }

Comment: Então veja se a resposta dada pelo @NatanFelipe resolve sua dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que pegar o seu button e utilizar o método setOnClickListener e lá você chama o método responsável por salvar os dados, dessa forma:

```
         botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             salvarDados();
         }
     });
```